# Import a package as an extension of another package with ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, npm, d3.js, ecmascript-6, import

In order to extend map projections in D3 it's suggested to require the packages like this:

```
const d3 = require("d3")
require("d3-geo-projection")(d3)
```

That way, you can use for example `d3-geo-projection`'s `geoAiry` method from the parent package:

```
d3.geoAiry()
```

Using `import` I'm doing this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as d3geo from 'd3-geo-projection'
```

But then the methods are not unified:

```
d3.geoMercator()
d3geo.geoAiry()
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as d3geo from 'd3-geo-projection'
d3geo(d3)
```

**So, in short, what is the equivalent of `require("d3-geo-projection")(d3)` in ES6 syntax?**

Comment: There is nothing wrong to import `d3` and `d3geo` separately. What is the meaning of their _unification_?

Comment: I want to be able to use d3.geoAiry(), which I can using require("d3-geo-projection")(d3), although geoAiry is a method not from d3 but from d3-geo-projection. I think it's correct to say I want to extend the d3 object with the d3-geo-projection methods

Comment: Have you tried `import d3 from 'd3'; import d3geo from 'd3-geo-projection'; d3geo(d3);` ? `import * as d3geo from ...` will always make `d3geo` an object, so you can't call that. You really need to look into how d3 exports its values.

Comment: `Object.assign(d3, d3geo)` should do the job.

Comment: Mike Bostock has his own take on how to import these modules: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/issues/128

Comment: @altocumulus: You could make that an answer.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, will do in a minute.

Comment: @FelixKling Who am I to disagree with Mike Bostock, but altocumulu's solution works as intended. Do you all think that's a bad practice for some reason?

Comment: I don't think it's bad. It's more about just doing what's necessary. And if you have the ability to just load what you need and access it directly instead of doing some kind of setup "dance", then that seems "better".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can use [`d3.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all properties from one import into the other, loosely speaking.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3geo from 'd3-geo-projection';

Object.assign(d3, d3geo);
```

This will make all your properties available under the `d3` object which is what you asked for:

```
d3.geoMercator()
d3.geoAiry()
// ...
```

However, should you do it that way? In my opinion, you should refrain from aggregating both your imports into one object. That seems to be some pre-ES6 reflex many developers give in to because they where taught to do it that way to ensure encapsulation by summing code into objects. The notion of encapsulation in JS has slightly changed with the introduction of modules, though.

Mike Bostok himself has his own take on the matter which he described in his answers to a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/issues/128) dealing with exactly the question you posted. He encouraged dropping the use of `import * as d3` altogether in favor of importing only those parts of a module you are actually going to use. Personally, I second that recommendation as I think it is the way modules should be used in modern JS code for sake of clarity and brevity. The only exception I would be willing to accept for my own code was the use of a lot, say 20+, of the exported members from a single module, although that might also indicate some code-smell suggesting you should consider refactoring your own module breaking it down into smaller pieces.

For even more modularization I usually prefer the usage of the individual modules instead of the whole d3 bundle which looks like this:

```
import { select, selectAll } from "d3-selection";
import { min, max } from "d3-array";
import { geoAiry } from "d3-geo-projection";
// ...
```